# the clear button from my javascript calculator doesnt work when the display is "full"

Tags: javascript, jquery

im creating a simple calculator project in javascript. its going pretty well, except for that last issue that ive found!
ive created a system to "read" when the display of the calculator is full, so you cant add more numbers once the limit has been reached. but, when the display is full, the clear button simply doesnt work! can somebody please help me and give me an answer as to why its not working? thanks in advance!

## system to check if the limit has been reached

```
if (mathDisplay.text().length > 18) {
    let maxSize = mathDisplay.text().trim().substring(0, 18);

    $('.limit-alert').addClass('limit-alert-active')

    $('.calculator-button').on('click', function () {
      if ($(this).hasClass('clear')) {
        maxSize = '';
        mathDisplay.text(maxSize);
      }
    })

    mathDisplay = maxSize;

    setTimeout(() => {
      $('.limit-alert').removeClass('limit-alert-active')
    }, 3000)
  }
```

## clear button normally

```
$('.calculator-button').on('click', function () {
 if ($(this).hasClass('clear')) {
    mathString = ''
    mathString = `0`
    mathDisplay.text(mathString);
  }
}
```

ive tried to change the variable position, ceating a new variable for the clean text, but couldnt find the right answer

Comment: What does `mathDisplay = maxSize;` do? For what I can see `mathDisplay` is a jQuery object and `maxSize` is a string. Did you maybe mean `mathDisplay.text(maxSize)` or `mathString = maxSize` ?

Comment: Your question doesn't reveal a whole lot about your code, so this is just speculation. Does the button always have the class "clear" when you click it?

Comment: @AbeMonk yes, it always have the class!

Comment: @HaoWu mathDisplay = maxSize; will send the string with the limited amount of numbers inside maxSize to the mathDisplay object, only displaying the limited amount of characters. yeah, i think i meant that hahaha. but when i try to do it that way `mathDisplay.text(maxSize)`, it doesnt work, the text can go further than the display limit

Answer (score 0):

On click clear is calling this of the button not the screen you want to clear call the id of the screen with $('#id') of the screen and then operations you want to do.